# Searching for gene expression data by cell line

Tags: database, cancer, differential-expression, cell-line

I have two cancer cell lines (OCI-Ly18 & riva) that I want to find gene expression data for, but I'm not aware of many gene expression databases that allow searching by cell-line without searching by gene.

I tried [Genevestigator](https://genevestigator.com) on the recommendation of this [thread](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_database_to_find_out_which_genes_are_expressed_in_which_cell_lines)
but found no data on either cell line.

What would be the best way to find gene expression data for these cell lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [Gene Expression Omnibus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/) - it looks like they have some datasets.

Comment: @JSneathThompson Consider marking the answer as accepted if it seems to be the best working solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [in this section](https://portals.broadinstitute.org/ccle/data/browseData?conversationPropagation=begin) of [Cancer Cell Line Encyclopedia](https://portals.broadinstitute.org/ccle/home). It has expression data for a lot of cancer cell lines. I have tried few times and found all cell lines I wanted, except HeLa. You just have to select mRNA expression data and download the file you prefer (raw data, gene-centric, etc.)